# How do I install Sony AVD Device Definitions on Android Studio 2.3.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, sony, android-virtual-device

I followed the link [Detailed Sony Add-on SDK installation](https://developer.sony.com/develop/archived-sdks/smartwatch-2-apis/get-started/install/detailed-installation/) and found there indeed step-by-step instructions. BUT! These instructions are for Eclipse, not for Android Studio!
Well, seems like I managed how to "Install the Sony Add-on SDK from the Android SDK Manager" (Step A).
But I see no way to "Install Sony’s device definitions" (Step B) because in the `Android Studio` there is no `extras` folder in the `Android SDK Manager`!

Eclipse's Android SDK Manager (image from Sony's site):
[image: Eclipse's Android SDK Manager]

Android Studio's SDK Manager:
[image: Android Studio's SDK Manager (SDK Platforms)]
[image: Android Studio's SDK Manager (SDK Tools)]

Can anybody explain me how to install `Sony Device Definitions` for `AVD` using `Android Studio`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Sony DeviceProfiles` is actually named just as `DeviceProfiles` in the `SDK Tools` tab!

[image: Device Profiles]

Comment: Bump.. I don't have this, maybe it changed. Is there link to add in `SDK Update Sites`?